# SQL function to parse multiple delimited id's (lead delimiter only) in a column and replace with text from table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a varchar column in a table containing values in this form:

```
case
  when @62159 >= @62160 then 1
  when @62160 <= 0  or (@62159 <0) then 0
  else @62159 / @62160
end
```

I need a function I can call within a query that will return a string where **each instance** of `@SurrogateKeyValue` has been replaced with the corresponding textual value from a known table.

The goal is to be able to call it like this, and the [TranslatedFormula] column would show the textual equivalents in place of the `@SurrogateKeyValue` instances:

```
select 
   FormulaID, FormulaText, friendlyText([FormulaText]) as TranslatedFormula 
from MyFormulaTable
```

I think it is "fairly" safe to assume the trailing delimiter will be a space, but perhaps would be safer to terminate when the first non-numerical character is found following the @.

At the moment, I'm not concerned at all about performance, but I suppose would like to take that into consideration eventually.

Entity Table where we'll retrieve the @EntityID values textual equivalent:

```
ENTITY
-------------------------------------    
EntityID | EntityName  
-------------------------------------  
62160    | Entity Friendly Name 0  
62161    | Entity Friendly Name 2  
62162    | Entity Friendly Name 3  
62163    | Entity Friendly Name 4  
62164    | Entity Friendly Name 5  
62165    | Entity Friendly Name 6
```

So......

```
@62160 blah blah blah @62161 yada yada yada @62162
```

...would be returned as:

```
[Entity Friendly Name 0] blah blah blah [Entity Friendly Name 2] yada yada yada [Entity Friendly Name 3]
```

(I've added some delimiters around the resolved names for clarity in the above example.)

Comment: You have us at an extreme disadvantage here. We have no idea what your project, tables or data look like. Without some details your request for help doesn't make much sense. Your case expression you posted has me at a complete loss. Are those supposed to be strings? variables? values?

Comment: @SeanLange Sorry, I added an example for clarification.

Comment: So you are saying you are going to have replacement tokens in a string and you want to replace those tokens with the values from a table? It is still extremely unclear what you are trying to do but I think you want to pass a string like "@62160 blah blah blah @62161 yada yada yada @62162" as your input?

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I would like to do, replace the \@EntityIdValue with the corresponding [EntityName], for ALL \@EntityID instances in the entire string.

Comment: Yuck that is super nasty. What have you tried so far? That is going to take some serious ugliness. You will first have to parse that into pieces. Then for each piece see if you find a replacement value. If it is there replace the token with the replacement value. This would be a lot easier in a programming language instead of sql but it is possible...just ugly, and likely pretty slow.

Comment: I agree.....google turns up something *possibly* similar:  http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=156474